# How can i start developing app on watchOS 3 SDK?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, swift, apple-watch

I can't find latest watchOS 3 SDK inside latest version of XCode 8 beta 2 even though they have mentioned it in their release notes. I have upgraded my Apple Watch to watchOS 3 beta 2 but I can't run my app on it:

> Error: No symbols for paired Apple Watch

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It's available in the latest XCode version 8.2. Download it from the apple website.