# Xcode 8 beta 2 / IOS10 beta 2 / WatchOS 3 beta 2 - no symbols for paired Apple Watch?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, swift, apple-watch

I can't run my app on Apple watch after upgrading it to watchOS 3 beta 2.
[image: See the error i am receiving while running my Watch App]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can i start developing app on watchOS 3 SDK?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38260031/how-can-i-start-developing-app-on-watchos-3-sdk)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38260031/how-can-i-start-developing-app-on-watchos-3-sdk . Isnt it the same question asked by you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ran into the same problem. I built and ran the App using a Simulator to make sure the App is OK, then plug my iPhone again and Xcode detected the paired watch and showing "installing symbols for paired watch". Wait until it finished and it can run on my device.